# Mac OS does not open TopCoder Arena to open

Tags: java, macos, exception

I'm running Mac OX 10.7.4 with the latest version of Java. I wanted to access TopCoder's Competition Arena, so I downloaded the .jnlp and tried to open it. However, I keep getting an error saying that the application is unsigned. I've attached screenshots of the error and the details thereof. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Contact TopCoder and tell them they should sign their applet.  They really ought to know that themselves of course.

Comment: This never happened to before I updated to the latest version of Java. It might be the case that TopCoder changed hasn't signed their applet, but it could also be that Java changed something (or Apple did something to change their affect their Java update). I wanted to know whether that was the cause here.

Answer (score 14):

I run `javaws -viewer` and deleted all instances of TC there. Running the jnlp afterwards worked.

The fix was suggested by `jthread` on TopCoder [here](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=752539&start=0&mc=3#1563630)

Comment: Nothing was listed for me inside that program.. and it still won't open.  Says unrecognized developer.  Running OSX Mavericks

Comment: @Erik did you find the solution to run on Mavericks?

Comment: I heard somewhere it was due to a Java Upgrade... frankly I gave up and switched to developing TCoder problems on my Windows 7 machine :(

Comment: Its probably just due to the fact OSX introduced this annoying "trusted developers" security feature. I had the same problem @Erik and just went to System Preferences->Security & Privacy->General Tab. If you've tried to run the jnlp recently there'll be an option to "run anyway", otherwise you can just allow apps from anywhere from here too.

Answer (score 5):

Via Terminal:

```
javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp
```

However, your security settings may warn you:

> This application cannot be downloaded because Java has been disabled
>   through the web. You can enable Java on this system using the Java
>   Control Panel.

Therefore, you might have to, via Terminal:

```
sudo javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

- In terminal: `javaws -viewer`
- Java Control Panel -> Security -> Edit Site List -> Add: `http://www.topcoder.com` and `https://www.topcoder.com` -> Save.
- Start Topcoder Arena applet again.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the fix listed above (removing instances by running javaws -viewer). It did not work for me. What did work was to locate the downloaded ContestAppletProd.jnlp file and running it from a terminal using the following command" javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp ". You want to run this in the folder containing the file ContestAppletProd.jnlp

Answer (score 0):

I have meet your problem today.The answer above is right,but you need to make sure you have the root
privileges.
so,the solution is

```
sudo javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp
```

that really work.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Java Control Panel` and go to `security` tab. First, add these sites to Exception Site List:

```
http://www.topcoder.com, http://topcoder.com, http://arena.topcoder.com
https://www.topcoder.com, https://topcoder.com, https://arena.topcoder.com
```

Then run the command `javaws -viewer` via terminal and delete existing TopCoder instances. Running `sudo javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp` should work without any problem.  In my case, I double clicked the ContestAppletProd.jnlp file and faced no issues.

Comment: Hi Sadeed and welcome to the community. Please specify which command you are talking about, since different answers mention different commands.