# java8u121 unable open topcoder arena

Tags: java, jnlp

The same problem on `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276668/mac-os-does-not-open-topcoder-arena-to-open`, but I can't resolve the issue of unsiged resource `http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/log4j-1.2.17.jar` even I mark it as an exception on the exception list.

```
JNLPException[category: 安全错误 : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/arena/" href="ContestAppletProd.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Competition Arena</title>
    <vendor>TopCoder, Inc.</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.topcoder.com"/>
    <description>TopCoder Contest Arena</description>
    <icon href="http://www.topcoder.com/images/favicon_new.gif"/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" max-heap-size="128m"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/arena-client-7.1.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/basic_type_serialization-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/client-socket-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/concurrent-1.0.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/encoder-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/logging-1.1.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/arena-shared-7.5.6.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/client-common-1.2.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/compeng-common-1.2.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/custom-serialization-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/http-tunnel-client-1.1.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/7.0/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.topcoder.client.contestApplet.runner.generic">
    <argument>www.topcoder.com</argument>
    <argument>5001</argument>
    <argument>http://tunnel1.topcoder.com/tunnel?dummy</argument>
    <argument>TopCoder</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp> ]
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had exactly the same problem on Windows

The following worked for me:

1) Open Java Control Panel
2) Security tab
3) Exception Site List / Edit Site List...

Add the following sites

```
http://topcoder.com
http://www.topcoder.com
http://arena.topcoder.com
https://topcoder.com
https://www.topcoder.com
https://arena.topcoder.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Good News - No More Java Security Issues with Topcoder Applet: While we are working on the new arena, we are also trying to reduce the issues you face with the Topcoder Java Applet With the new version of the Topcoder Java Applet you donât have to add anything in Java Security Exceptions.

New Version: http://www.topcoder.com/contest/arena/ContestAppletProd7.2.jnlp